# Show menu for NSStatusItem with view

Tags: click, nsmenu, nsstatusitem

I have an NSStatusItem with a custom view (TimeView) set but this blocks the click from displaying the NSMenu associated with the `NSStatusItem`. If I disable the view for the `NSStatusItem` then the menu shows correctly, however, if I enable it then nothing happens when I click on the view.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        statusItem.view = TimeView(statusItem: statusItem)//Commenting out this line provides the correct functionality for displaying the menu
        statusItem.menu = statusMenu
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }    

}
```

Many thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way of accomplishing this. You can use `NSStatusItem`'s`popUpStatusItemMenu(menu: NSMenu)` method to show the menu in the views `mouseDown(event: NSEvent)` method.

However this does not take care of highlighting the NSStatusItem. The simplest way I could find to do that is to make the view conform to `NSMenuDelegate` and set it as the menu delegate. Then you can override the `menuWillOpen(menu: NSMenu)` and `menuDidClose(menu: NSMenu)` methods in the following manner:

```
func menuWillOpen(menu: NSMenu) {
    drawHighlight(true)
}

func menuDidClose(menu: NSMenu) {
    drawHighlight(false)
}

func drawHighlight(highlight:Bool) {
    let image = NSImage(size: self.frame.size)
    image.lockFocus()
    statusItem.drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect(self.bounds, withHighlight: highlight)
    image.unlockFocus()
    self.layer?.contents = image
}
```